# Poles of the L-series of the elliptic curve which has CM

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be the elliptic curve which has CM.  It is well known that the L-series of the elliptic curve which has CM is Hecke L-series.  On the other hand, it is pointed out that Hecke L-series has no pole. Is it right to consider that the L-series of $E/\mathbb{Q}$ has no pole?

As usual, let the local part be $L_p(T) = 1 - a_pT + pT^2$ when the curve has good reduction at *p*.  Setting $T = p^{-s}$, we will think of $L_p(s) = L_p(p^{-s})$. Let $L(E/\mathbb{Q}, s) = \Pi_pL_p(s)^{-1}$. Suppose that $L(E/\mathbb{Q}, s)$ has no pole. Fix a prime number $p_0$. If $L_{p0}(s_0) = 0$ then it yields that $L_p(s_0) = 0$ for infinitely many prime numbers *p’s*, because $\Pi_pL_p(s)^{-1}$ is absolutely convergent at the complex number $s = s_0 $. Is this right?

Cordially,
M. Shimoinuda.

Answer (score 4):

It is a general fact that if $E$ is any elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ (CM or otherwise) its Hasse-Weil $L$-series has no poles, at least if you multiply by the appropriate $\Gamma$ factor. (This follows from work of Hecke and Deuring for CM curves, and for non-CM curves it is a much deeper theorem relying on the fact that all elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$ are modular.)

But I think your argument regarding zeros of the local $L$-factors does not work, because although the $L$-function is defined and holomorphic for all $s$, that does not mean that the Euler product expansion converges for all $s$. The domain of holomorphy of the function isn't necessarily the same as the domain of convergence of the Euler product.

Comment: To take a simpler case, consider the Riemann zeta-function's Euler product $\prod_p 1/(1-1/p^s)$, which is valid for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$. At $s = 0$ each Euler factor blows up, but that hardly means the Riemann zeta-function has a pole at $s = 0$ (in fact $\zeta(0) = -1/2$).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers are very helpful.        - M.Shimoinuda

Comment: The $\Gamma$-function has no zero, therefore $\Gamma$-factors can never kill poles, they can only introduce them. So the (true) statement that the complete Hasse-Weil $L$-function (with the $\Gamma$-factors attached) has no pole is stronger than the statement that the Hasse-Weil $L$-series (without the $\Gamma$-factors attached) has no pole.

Comment: To be clear, you mean $L(s,E/\mathbb{Q}) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-1_{p^2 \nmid N} a_pp^{-s}+1_{p \nmid N} p^{1-2s}}$ the L-function of $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is entire (as it is the L-function of a cusp form). But the Hasse-Weil zeta function $\zeta(s,E/\mathbb{Q}) = \frac{\zeta(s) \zeta(s-1)}{L(s,E/\mathbb{Q})} = \prod_p \exp(\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{\# E(\mathbb{F}_{p^m})}{m} p^{-sm})$ is only meromorphic and has many poles.